# WPF Textbox - How to save text without the wrapping-paragraph

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, textbox, word-wrap

I load some texts from a database with different lengths into a textbox. (From 1 character to 1000 words...)

I use `TextWrapping="Wrap"`, so if the text is to big for the width of the textbox, it will create a new line....

By saving the text, the added paragraph from `TextWrapping="Wrap"` will also be saved. But I don't want this. The original text shouldn't be changed in any way...

How can I display the text on a new line in the textbox without adding a "real" paragraph?

Is there a way I can determine if the paragraph was added from `TextWrapping="Wrap"` or if it belong to the original text?

Thanks

Comment: How do you save the text? By getting the text from the Text property of the TextBox you get the content of the TextBox as plain text...

Comment: The `TextWrapping` property only affects the *display* of the text in the `TextBox`, it does not change the source text in any way.

Comment: @Eirik I get the content of the textbox, as you mentioned in your comment, by using the Text property.

Comment: @StevenRands Thanks for your comment, you are right. The source text isn't affected in any way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@StevenRands** mentioned, the source text won't be changed in any way by using `TextWrapping`.

It only affects the display of the text inside the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if you used text Wrapping,it wont affect the original source text.But anyways Before saving back to database you can remove the new line constants from your text box text which will give you the original text loaded from db.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. Text-Wrapping doesn't affect the original text right? Then why would i have to remove the new line constants from the textbox to get the original text back?

Comment: @ jklinger :That's just a work around that you can try to get your code worked.